# Группировка данных в запросе

Tags: запрос, sql

**Делаю запрос**

```
select _sIDPRZ.idprz,name, polis.polistype, polisdate,
COUNT(*) AS Kol
from polis
join _sIDPRZ on polis.idprz=_sIDPRZ.idprz
where polistype=3
and polisdates between '2011-05-01 00:00:00' and '2012-10-31 23:59:59'
and polis.polisdateF is  null
GROUP BY _sIDPRZ.idprz,name, polistype,polisdate
order by _sIDPRZ.idprz,polistype, polisdate'
```

Выдает ответ

```
idprz         name               polistype       polisdate               Kol
402 УПРЗ г. Вязьма             3         2011-06-14 00:00:00.000          2
402 УПРЗ г. Вязьма             3         2011-06-17 00:00:00.000          76
402 УПРЗ г. Вязьма             3         2011-06-20 00:00:00.000          18
.......
413 УПРЗ п. Новодугино     3         2012-03-02 00:00:00.000          5
.......
```

ВОПРОС: как оформить корректно выборку по дате, чтобы ответ выдавался не на каждый день, а общей суммой по конкретному `idprz`?

Answer (score 5):

```
select _sIDPRZ.idprz,name, COUNT(*) AS Kol
from polis
join _sIDPRZ on polis.idprz=_sIDPRZ.idprz
where polistype=3
and polisdates between '2011-05-01 00:00:00' and '2012-10-31 23:59:59'
and polis.polisdateF is  null
GROUP BY _sIDPRZ.idprz,name
order by _sIDPRZ.idprz
```

[Группировка](http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_getting_summarizing_values.html)

Comment: не пойму мне вставить функцию SUM надо, или я не правильно группирую
я только учусь и не все так быстро понимаю....

Comment: Если вы считаете количество строк, то используйте COUNT, если вам нужно просуммировать значения в столбце, тогда SUM.

Comment: мне нужно просуммировать значения в столбце по разнам группам. то есть сумма полисов за период группы 401 - 15, группы 402 - 16. а у меня получается не так. он считает сумму за конкретный день. а при выборе интервала, выдает мнго групп 402, 401 и так далее...

Comment: select _sIDPRZ.idprz,name, 
    sum(CASE WHEN _sIDPRZ.idprz>='402' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Kol
    from polis
    join _sIDPRZ on polis.idprz=_sIDPRZ.idprz
    where polistype=3
    and polisdates between '2011-05-01 00:00:00' and '2012-10-31      23:59:59'
    and polis.polisdateF is  null
    GROUP BY _sIDPRZ.idprz,name
    order by _sIDPRZ.idprz

решил проблему так, но не уверен что это правильно))